# Google Drive APIs returns 500 - Internal error when page size exceeds 150

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am using Google Drive's java Client Library to list and download files from my application. When trying to list files, I am getting 500 Internal Server error from Google.

```
{ "code" : 500, "errors" : [ { "domain" : "global", "message" : "Internal Error", "reason" : "internalError" } ], "message" : "Internal Error" }
```

When debugging this further, I found that the issue occurs only when trying to list files and folders from the root folder, with the page size set to more than 150 and above. The issue is not occurring when
files/folders  inside a folder are listed with page size above 150.

The total number of files/folders in my root folder is less than 150 and I am trying to fetch only file/folder names in the API request using fields parameter.

Can someone clarify me on why such error occurs?

Comment: Maybe because you must not set such a large page size and instead use pagination.

Comment: For all other accounts I am using, it is working fine with 150+ pagesize.
Error is occurring only for one particular gdrive account

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Have you tested using the default 100 page size for the root? I am also wondering if adding the same parameter for that particular drive account over their "Try it" would land some insight in case it does work from there and we are looking at just the rate limits: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Comment: @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz

Tried from 'Try it'. The same error occurs there as well even with the default 100 page size

Comment: Is this a Google Workspace user and the only one being affected by it ?

Comment: yes he is the only one affected
@RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz